# relation between innodb barracuda file format and seagate

Tags: mysql, innodb, barracuda

I learned that the default file format of innodb is barracuda. But I know that barracuda is famous hard disk brand of seagate. Are there any relationship between barracuda file format and hard disk?

Comment: 'default file format of innodb is barracuda.' - really? the default on my installation is Antelope.

Comment: It's the default since 5.7.7. And no, there's no connection to seagate.

Comment: I think it is a coincidence.

Answer (score 1):

I've never heard anyone claim there was any connection between the Seagate hard drive series and the InnoDB file format. For all I know or can find on the internet, both technologies were named independently after [the 1977 rock song by Heart](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PeMvMNpvB5M).

The Seagate Barracuda series of hard drive products was first launched in 1991. It was the first 7200rpm hard drive. Seagate was based in Scotts Valley, California.

InnoDB was developed by software engineers based in Helsinki, Finland. The company Innobase Oy was founded in 1995.

Were the engineers at Innobase Oy familiar with Seagate hard drives? It's a good assumption that they were aware of Seagate, because the database software engineers would have been focused on current high performance storage technology.

The Barracuda file format for InnoDB was announced at the 2008 MySQL User Conference. It was implemented in the "plugin" InnoDB storage engine, which was an alternative way of including the storage engine at that time. MySQL 5.1.38 was the first release to include the InnoDB plugin, and it was released 2009-09-01.

The preceding InnoDB file format, used as the default in MySQL 5.0 and 5.1, then became known as "Antelope."

I've always assumed that Antelope and Barracuda were mnemonics for the sequence of letters like "A" then "B" and so on, I guess because they wanted something more catchy than v1.0 and v2.0.

If they ever introduce a third InnoDB file format, I expect it will be named after another animal whose name starts with "C," like "Chameleon" or "Capybara."